# How to generate a Linux Apache password file on a PC running Windows 7?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, xampp, htpasswd, md5

My development machine is Windows. I use the htpasswd program that is part of the [Windows XAMPP package](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), version 1.7.7, to generate a Windows Apache password file.

> C:\xampp\apache\bin\htpasswd.exe -bc .htpasswd usename password

I need to generate a password file for a Redhat Linux machine but have no access to the htpasswd program on that machine. If I can generate a valid Linux Apache passwd on Windows then I can FTP it over to the Linux system.

[The htpasswd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html) says that I can use the -d flag to force crypt() encryption which should work on Linux instead of the default MD5 encryption that works on Windows.

My problem is that

> C:\xampp\apache\bin\htpasswd.exe -bcd .htpasswd usename password

generates a file but gives a message which says "Automatically using MD5 format".

How do I generate a valid Apache password file for a Linux machine from a Windows PC?

Comment: Apache on Linux will work happily with MD5 password hashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online tool such as [this](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator) to get the job done.